# convert integer to std_logic

Tags: vhdl

Suppose you have a loop

```
for i in 1 downto 0 loop
    for j in 1 downto 0 loop
        tS0 <= i;
```

But I need to convert the integer (which is natural) to std_logic. **tS0** is declared as std_logic. I am only doing it one bit (0 or 1). That is, my **i** and **j** can only represent the value {0,1}.

I think I am heading to the wrong approach here. Can someone please tell me what should I do instead?

I don't think std_logic has to_unsigned method. i tried letting **tS0** to be a vector (1 down to 0), and assigned like **tS0(0) <= i**, and etc. But it still didn't work out.

Thank you very much!

Comment: http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/4482/vhdl-converting-from-an-integer-type-to-a-std-logic-vector

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You will need to use a vector, either unsigned or std_logic, but it can be one bit long.  ie:

```
signal tS0 : unsigned (0 downto 0);
...
tS0 <= to_unsigned(i, tS0'length);
```

...or...

```
signal tS0: std_logic_vector(0 downto 0);
...
tS0 <= std_logic_vector(to_unsigned(i,tS0'length);
```

Answer (score 13):

There is no need to convert from integers. You can just iterate over the std_logic datatype:

```
for i in std_logic range '0' to '1' loop
   ts0 <= i;
end loop;
```

Comment: Nice one! Thank you!!

Answer (score 7):

I'd write a function:

```
function to_std_logic(i : in integer) return std_logic is
begin
    if i = 0 then
        return '0';
    end if;
    return '1';
end function;
```

then use:

```
ts0 <= to_std_logic(i);
```

Comment: For me, this is a much more useful and accurate answer than the accepted one.

Answer (score 4):

You can do it like this. It looks a little simplier.

```
ts0 <= std_logic(to_unsigned(i, 1)(0));
```

You will build a unsigned vector by using the to_unsigned function. Then you grap the lowest bit and convert it to std_logic and then you assign it to the signal.

This is how it works fine :-).

Answer (score 1):

Improving on a previous answer, you could write:

```
ts0 <= to_unsigned(i, 1)(0);
```

Provided you include the "numeric_std" library, in which that function is defined:

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.numeric_std.all;
```

You can skip the explicit cast to "std_logic" type because the return type of "to_unsigned()" is an array of "std_logic" itself:

```
type UNSIGNED is array (NATURAL range <>) of STD_LOGIC;
```